# pass data to different functions

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string with IDs and I want to pass the string from a View, depending on the pressed button, to two different functions.

I want one or two forms with the string in an hidden input. And two buttons: "do method A" and "do method B".

I tried to fill the string into two form with JQuery but only the first input is filled. I tried it with `$(".classname:first")`and `$(".classname:last")` (for some reason the HTML helper ignores my modification of the class or the id).

How can I call different functions depending on the button I pressed?

Or how can I fill two separate inputs with the same classname?

Or how can I access the child of an selector in JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Set out your `HTML` as follows:

```
<form id="hidform" action="/" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.str, "value=\"0\">
    <input id="method-a" data-action="methoda" type="submit" value="do method a">
    <input id="method-b" data-action="methodb" type="submit" value="do method b">
</form>
```

As you can see, the action isn't set on my form, it looks like it will just post to your home page (which isn't what you want). However, if you look at the `input` tags I've added a data attribute `data-action`. Data attributes aren't a requirement for this solution, it's just my preference. Then for your `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidform input').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        $('#hidform').attr('action', action).submit();
    });
});
```

This will prevent the default action of the submit buttons, apply the value from `data-action` to the form's `action` attribute and then submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

I added a div around the submitbuttons and the hidden input an inserted the tag `onmousemove="$(this).find('#str').val(ids)`.

Like that:

`@using(Html.BeginForm("MethodA", "XYZ", FormMethod.Post, "name=\"hidform\" id=\"hidform\"")) {
        <div onmousemove="$(this).find('#str').val(ids)">
            <input type="submit" value="do method A"/>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.str, "value=\"0\"")
        </div>
    }
    @using(Html.BeginForm("MethodB", "XYZ", FormMethod.Post, "name=\"hidform\" id=\"hidform\"")) { 
        <div onmousemove="$(this).find('#str').val(ids)">
            <input type="submit" value="do method B"/>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.str, "value=\"0\"")
        </div>
    }`

Comment: This is a horrible approach.

Comment: why? how can I improve it?